# Laravel 5.4: SQLSTATE[42000] 1071 Specified key was too long error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Поставил на хост **чистый** laravel 5.4 через composer, сразу запустил миграции и получил ошибку:

```
$ php artisan migrate

Migration table created successfully.


[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

(SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))


PDOException]

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Что не так и как исправить?

Comment: У меня версия Mysql 5.7.31 и ошибка появляется Schema::defaultStringLength(191); не помогает И в ошибке не "max key length is 767 bytes"
a "max key length is 1000 bytes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На русском ответа нет, а на английском ответ есть тут - [Laravel 5.4: Specified key was too long error](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error):

В Laravel 5.4 изменась кодировка по умолчанию для базы данных (теперь это  utf8mb4 для поддержки emoji). Ошибка Specified key was too long error проявляется только для MySQL ниже v5.7.7 и в старых версиях MariaDB.

Для исправления этой ошибки внесите следующие изменения в файл app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

1. Добавьте строку в блоке use:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   ```
2. Добавьте в метод boot строку:

   ```
   public function boot()
   {
       Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
   }
   ```